# Java Serialization not working how I expected

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize an `ArrayList<Prescription>` using an `ObjectOutputStream`

Here is the `Prescription` class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Prescription implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4432845389029948144L;

    private String name;
    private String dosage;
    private int originalQuantity = 0;
    private int quantityRemaining = 0;
    private String prescribingPharmacy;

    private long dateStarted = 0;

    private boolean taken_AM = false;
    private boolean taken_Noon = false;
    private boolean taken_PM = false;

    private boolean taken_Mon = false;
    private boolean taken_Tue = false;
    private boolean taken_Wed = false;
    private boolean taken_Thu = false;
    private boolean taken_Fri = false;
    private boolean taken_Sat = false;
    private boolean taken_Sun = false;

    public Prescription(){
        this.name = "Unknown";
    }

    public Prescription(String name, String dosage, int quantity, String pharmacy){
        this.name = name;
        this.dosage = dosage;
        this.originalQuantity = quantity;
        this.quantityRemaining = quantity;
        this.prescribingPharmacy = pharmacy;
        this.dateStarted = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }

    public void setTaken(boolean AM, boolean Noon, boolean PM){
        this.taken_AM = AM;
        this.taken_Noon = Noon;
        this.taken_PM = PM;
    }

    public void setTaken(boolean Mon, boolean Tue, boolean Wed, boolean Thu,
        boolean Fri, boolean Sat, boolean Sun){
        this.taken_Mon = Mon;
        this.taken_Tue = Tue;
        this.taken_Wed = Wed;
        this.taken_Thu = Thu;
        this.taken_Fri = Fri;
        this.taken_Sat = Sat;
        this.taken_Sun = Sun;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

Yet, when I try to do this, I get a `NotSerializableException` on the `Prescription` class. This doesn't make any sense to me, as I am only using primitive data types and `String`.

Here is the function I am using to do the serialization:

```
public boolean saveToFile(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = this.context.openFileOutput(LIST_SAVE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(this.pList);
        oos.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the serialization code will help.

Comment: Clean build, same issue.

Comment: what is the object this.pList?

Comment: That is the `ArrayList<Prescription>`

Comment: Not really part of the problem, but you really should name `setTaken(..)` and `setTaken(...)` to `setTime(...)` and `setDays(...)` or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<Prescription> d = new ArrayList<Prescription>();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\Prescription.dat")));
        d.add(new Prescription());
        oos.writeObject(d);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

works without any exceptions with the class you posted, so there's something you're not telling us :-)

Comment: Does it matter if the `List` is empty, because it very well may be in most cases for me?

Comment: Got it working, you were right. I was just trying to read later from an older serialized file that I needed to clear out. Thanks.